# Displaying messages from IBM MQ

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I created application which can connect, send or read messages from queue. In this moment I want to show message (not read!) from queue. Can you help me with this issue?
I should use MQC.MQOO_BROWSE parameter when I try get access to queue?

I tried create method like below:

```
public ShowMessage ShowMessagesFromQueue(IRequiredParameters parameters)
{
    ShowMessage queue;
    try
    {
        queue = new ShowMessage(_manager.AccessQueue(parameters.QueueName, MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE));
        Console.WriteLine("Message from queue: ");     
    }
    catch (MQException exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

and I don't know how should I implement class below:

```
public class ShowMessage
{
     private MQQueue _queue;
     public ShowMessage(MQQueue queue)
    {
        _queue = queue;
    }

public string Show()
{
    var message = new MQMessage();
    try
    {
        return message.ReadString(message.(dontKnowWhatUseHere);
    }
    catch (MQException exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is good idea?

Comment: What queue are we talking about here ? What have you tried so far ? and some code snippet could help us help you solve your problem.

Comment: I am talking about local queue and I added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I resolved it.
In my Show method I had to add more option like below:

```
public void Show()
{
    var message = new MQMessage();
    try
    {
        var getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
        getMessageOptions.Options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
        _queue.Get(message, getMessageOptions);
        var msg = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
        Console.WriteLine("Preview of message: " + msg);
    }
    catch (MQException exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```